# Trying to execute a shell() command in the preBuildSteps of a Jenkins DSL mavenJob

Tags: jenkins-job-dsl

I have done a lot of investigating trying to find examples of running shell() script commands in a preBuildSteps of a mavenJob. All I have found provides simple examples. For example:

```
mavenJob('example-1') {
    preBuildSteps {
        shell("echo 'run before Maven'")
    }
}
```

I would like to execute a linux bash script. for example:

shell("bash /scripts/pom.xml.exists.sh")

When I execute, I am receiving the following error message:

- bash /scripts/pom.xml.exists.sh
  bash: /scripts/pom.xml.exists.sh: No such file or directory

Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong? Conversely, maybe a shell command that will tell me what directory I am supposedly in. Perhaps that will let me know why I get the not found message.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

try

```
shell("bash scripts/pom.xml.exists.sh")
```

or even

```
shell("scripts/pom.xml.exists.sh")
```

Looks like you're using absolute path by accident, but you want relative path.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I just tried this. it did not work. same error. I guess part of what I think I need to determine is where I am when trying to execute. How can I determine the directory structure?

Comment: pwd is the shell built-in command that will give you the Present Working Directory

Comment: I have been trying pwd but I do not get any output when I try it. here is an example of the syntax I have been trying. I have tried a few combinations. That is part of what I am asking. What is the syntax for commands like pwd?

shell("bash pwd".execute().text)

Comment: you're overthinking it. just do 

'shell("pwd")`